# Sending mail using postfix in linux

Tags: linux, shell, smtp, postfix-mta, mutt

I've setup postfix on my ubuntu machine and also passed the login credentials (qs we're using 587 port)

But while running mail or mutt command it's not giving any error but mail.log showing status as bounced.

I've checked and able to telnet to the smtp server on port 587

Comment: Do you see error messages when you run `systemctl status postfix`?

Comment: Yeah it's running

Comment: Could you include log file entries generated by sending attempts?

Comment: Status=deferred(delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server xxx.domain[ip]: generic failure)